# Filter nested list class in core data by swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to filter a nested class and show it in table view by search. My classes are:

```
class group {
 var name: String?
 var words: [word]?

}

class word {
 var text: String?
}
```

I have this object for searching the following code:

```
var groups: [group] = { ... }
var filterdGroups: [group]?
```

I want to search a word in the `groups[...].words` and show it in `UITableView` like:

- group 1 (section*)

  - word1 (cell)
  - word2 (cell)
  - word3 (cell)
- group 1 (section*)

  - word12 (cell)
  - word24 (cell)
  - word35 (cell)
- [...]
  As you see `group.name` is the `section name` and `word.text` is the `cell` in `UITableView`. I want to find an optimized way to filter `words` of each `group` like the following code:

  ```
  { ...
    for group in groups {
     guard var wordList = group.words else {
       retun
      }
       wordList.filter((word) -> Bool in 
             return word.text.contains(searchText)
            )
        // ???? How can I give it to `group` and filter `group`

   }
    ... }
  ```

The problem is group is a class in core data so I can't make a new object of it and I don't want to put all of them in new object model as it's not optimized.

Comment: Can you please read about NSFtchedResultsController. It is meant for core data to be represented in table views and collection views. https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: @user1046037 I read about it but I wonder how can I do it without `NSFtchedResultsController`.